# Java check if a scan input is both a specific string and only three digits

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

I have a project that is asking, "Order is entered by the user. The order either begins with FB or SB and then has three digits after those letters. Must check to be sure the order number is either letter code and only three digits." in java.

ex.
Create order number [FB or SB for type of gift and three integers]: FB343

I'm struggling to find how to validate both in one input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a *regular expression* to me. You can use a `Pattern` and `Matcher` to test if the given order matches the `Pattern`; does it start with F or S then B and then three digits. Like,

```
String[] arr = { "SB123", "FB124", "CBXXX", "FB1234" };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[SF]B\\d{3}");
for (String s : arr) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.printf("%s %b%n", s, m.matches());
}
```

Outputs

```
SB123 true
FB124 true
CBXXX false
FB1234 false
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex should do the trick.

Just run Pattern.matches() on the sequence ^((FB)|(SB){1})([0-9]{3})$

Something like

```
public class Matcher(string){
bool = Pattern.matches(^((FB)|(SB){1})([0-9]{3})$), string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to further enhance the Order Number validation:

```
String orderNumber = "fb323"; // The Order Number.

int minNumber = 100;  // The min value that will ever be in a Order. Number
int maxNumber = 2500; // The max value that will ever be in a Order. Number
int curNumber = Integer.parseInt(orderNumber.replaceAll("\\D", ""));

if (orderNumber.matches("(?i)[SF]B\\d{3,}") && (curNumber >= minNumber && curNumber <= maxNumber)) {
    System.out.println("VALID!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("INVALID!");
}
```